# Как найти код Kotlin в проекте

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, build

Пищу приложение на Android на JAVA. При анализе apk в classes.dxp вижу папки kotlin и kotlinx размером около 2 мБайт. На котлине ничего не писал в build.gradle ничего вроде нет

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.sh.uch_mk"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 31
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation "ru.tinkoff.decoro:decoro:1.1.1"
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha14"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.0.0'
}
```

build.grandle Project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here;  they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Как найти в проекте то что подтягивает эти зависимости?

Comment: Запустите в консоли проекта `gradle MODULE:dependencies`, где MODULE - имя модуля в проекте о котором хотите узнать подробности. Там и ищите, кто что подключает.

Comment: Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, а это какая консоль? Где её найти?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

Comment: Спасибо уже сделал. Оказалась проблема в implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависимости с `-ktx` предназначены для kotlin, они и тянут его в апк

Comment: И где это искать?

Comment: там, где зависимости указываете,  implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'

Comment: Туплю, спасибо за подсказку. Убрал, но проблема полностью не ушла. kollinx исчезло, а kotlin, хоть и уменьшился до 1 мБ но не ушел полностью. Что еще может быть?

Comment: Нужно смотреть на build gradle проекта (в вопросе buld gradle модуля), возможно там ещё Котлин подключен

Comment: А куда смотреть build.grandle Project? Добавил в 1 пост